# Bootstrap3 Product Carousel not working properly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some problem in `Bootstrap3 Carousel` which I found on [here](http://www.bootply.com/132400)

 I am using `Bootstrap3`, the output I am having is only one image at a time.

**Html**

```
    <div class="container img-responsive" style="background: #d9e5e9;
 padding-left: -0px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px; margin: 20px auto; width: 980px;">
    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
    <a href="#"><img src="~/images/contact.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
    <a href="#"><img src="~/images/contact1.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
    <a href="#"><img src="~/images/contact2.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left">
    </i></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**Script and style**

```
<style>
    .carousel-inner .active.left {
        left: -25%;
    }

    .carousel-inner .next {
        left: 25%;
    }

    .carousel-inner .prev {
        left: -25%;
    }

    .carousel-control {
        width: 4%;
    }

        .carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
            margin-left: 15px;
            background-color: #036ca6;
        }
</style>
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myCarousel').carousel({
                interval: 4000
            })

            $('.carousel .item').each(function () {
                var next = $(this).next();
                if (!next.length) {
                    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
                }
                next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

                for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    next = next.next();
                    if (!next.length) {
                        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
                    }

                    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

*The problem is only that it is showing one image at a time but it is supposed to show 4 images*. 
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you add your code so we can compare what you're doing?

Comment: thanks for reply,,, i have updated

Comment: i dont have repo so i could show the output picture

Comment: Can you provide a Fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, I would check to make sure that you've properly included all the necessary scripts and stylesheets needed to run bootstrap.  This should include at least a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="boostrap.css">` and a `<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>`.  I've linked to the CDNs below if you don't want to store them locally.

If this isn't the issue, take a look at your `for` loop and make sure that it's set to run enough times to append all the children.  Right now, it will only run twice.

Finally, check your html.  You said you wanted to display four images, but your only have three included.

Bootstrap CSS & JS CDN: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

jQuery CDN (you'll probably want this too): http://code.jquery.com